# Remove duplicates from table B that is JOINed to unique rows on table A

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I'm a novice still with SQL, and my query is getting to a level of complexity where I can't quite isolate exactly what I need or what I would call this problem. As such, I had a lot of trouble when searching for an answer. Query is at the bottom to keep clean reading space. My goal with this query is to return the status that occurs after 305, when modified by a list of people, based on dates provided.

What it's doing that I didn't expect is that if one member goes into 305 twice before one of those in the list, there are two rows and my counts get weird. Here's an example of what it currently gives:

```
+----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+
| MemberID | OldStatus  | OldUser |  OldDt   | NewStatus  | NewUser |  NewDt   |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+
| member1  |        305 | A       | 11/9/16  |        801 | K       | 11/10/16 |
| member1  |        305 | B       | 9/9/16   |        801 | K       | 11/10/16 |
| member2  |        305 | A       | 10/3/16  |        205 | D       | 10/7/16  |
| member2  |        305 | A       | 10/11/16 |        310 | D       | 10/14/16 |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------- +
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
+----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+
| MemberID | OldStatus  | OldUser |  OldDt   | NewStatus  | NewUser |  NewDt   |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+
| member1  |        305 | A       | 11/9/16  |        801 | K       | 11/10/16 |
| member2  |        305 | A       | 10/3/16  |        205 | D       | 10/7/16  |
| member2  |        305 | A       | 10/11/16 |        310 | D       | 10/14/16 |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+
```

That being said, I understand roughly why it's doing that with my join. What I don't understand is how to make it stop doing that, but ONLY when table B is identical for the same member. The same member can occur twice, but only if table B has a different result from when it's changed.

Furthermore, my query is somewhat cobbled together. This is my approach to the problem, but it looks really redundant. If anybody has a more elegant or robust solution or improvement to my code, I would appreciate feedback. I'm on Access 2010 and MS SQL, no access to back end tools.

Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.memberid,
                A.statuscd   AS 305_Status,
                A.updateuser AS 305_User,
                A.updatedt   AS 305_Date,
                B.statuscd   AS New_Status,
                B.updateuser AS New_User,
                B.updatedt   AS New_Date
FROM   v_queue_history AS A
       INNER JOIN v_queue_history AS B
               ON ( A.memberid = B.memberid
                    AND A.updatedt >= ( DATE() - 365 )
                    AND A.statuscd = '305'
                    AND B.statuscd <> '305'
                    AND B.updateuser IN ( 'a', 'd',
                                          'g',
                                          'h',
                                          'j', 'k', 'p'
                                          ,
                                          'm'
                                          ,
                                          's', 'w',
                                          'k' )
                    AND B.updatedt > A.updatedt )
WHERE  B.updatedt = (SELECT Min(updatedt)
                     FROM   v_queue_history AS C
                     WHERE  C.memberid = A.memberid
                            AND C.updatedt > A.updatedt
                            AND C.statuscd <> "305")
       AND ( Year(B.updatedt) * 53 + Datepart("m", B.updatedt) =
                   Year(DATE()) * 53 + Datepart("m", DATE())
                   - [how many months ago would you like to look?] );
```

Comment: It would help if your sample data had some indication of column names. And the expected results would be nice. [This](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) has some useful tips for asking database questions.

Comment: Alright, I modified my post to better fit your requests. If I need to randomly generate a bunch of junk data I can, but this should display what change I want to make a bit better.

Comment: I tried something to this effect but it shoots back an error.

INNER JOIN V_Queue_History as D
ON (A.MemberID = D.MemberId,
AND B.UpdateDt <> D.UpdateDt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to find the MAX date for a 305 status.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.memberid,
                A.statuscd   AS 305_Status,
                A.updateuser AS 305_User,
                A.updatedt   AS 305_Date,
                B.statuscd   AS New_Status,
                B.updateuser AS New_User,
                B.updatedt   AS New_Date
FROM   v_queue_history AS A
       INNER JOIN v_queue_history AS B
               ON ( A.memberid = B.memberid
                    AND A.updatedt >= ( DATE() - 365 )
                    AND A.statuscd = '305'
                    AND B.statuscd <> '305'
                    AND B.updateuser IN ( 'a', 'd',
                                          'g',
                                          'h',
                                          'j', 'k', 'p'
                                          ,
                                          'm'
                                          ,
                                          's', 'w',
                                          'k' )
                    AND B.updatedt > A.updatedt )
WHERE  B.updatedt = (SELECT Min(updatedt)
                     FROM   v_queue_history AS C
                     WHERE  C.memberid = A.memberid
                            AND C.updatedt > A.updatedt
                            AND C.statuscd <> "305")
       AND A.updatedt = (SELECT MAX(updatedt)
                         FROM v_queue_history AS D
                         WHERE  D.memberid = A.memberid
                            AND D.updatedt < B.updatedt
                            AND D.statuscd = "305")
       AND ( Year(B.updatedt) * 53 + Datepart("m", B.updatedt) =
                   Year(DATE()) * 53 + Datepart("m", DATE())
                   - [how many months ago would you like to look?] );
```

Comment: I think I understand what you were going for, but it didn't cause any changes to my results. I tried it both as you have it written and with the MAX() on B.UpdateDt, but still no change. Thank you though.

Comment: The new clause I added to the WHERE should filter out all but the max A.updatedt.

Comment: Well look at that. Works like a charm now. If you don't mind me picking your brain a bit further, why is that this doesn't also filter out results where there are multiple cnlymemberIDs but different results on B?

Comment: In your main join, you're saying B records need to have dates greater than A records. Then in the WHERE, you want B records that equal the MIN C dates that are still greater than the A dates. Essentially "Give me the floor value that is still greater than A". We want to do the inverse with A. "Give me the ceiling value that still less than A". Using the aggregate functions Min() and Max() return a single date to compare against. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, that helps. Thanks again!